# How to deal with security token with SOAP in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I am trying get data from a SOAP server in PHP. So far i manage to connect with a username and a password and to retrieve a security token. Now i am trying to use a function to get more data. But it doesn't work. I always get the message :

> Error: SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request in C:\Users\user1\Documents\wamp\www\soap\index.php:93 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__soapCall('exportOrder', Array) #2 {main}

I have the feeling it's related to the way i handle the securityToken. How shall i handle it in my code?

I am a beginner in SOAP and PHP. Any help would appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my PHP code :

```
<?php

$wsdl = "http://abcd.org/abcdServer/webservices/auth/ExternalOrderWebService?wsdl"; 

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'exceptions' => 1,
        'trace' => 1,
        'location'=>$wsdl
        )
    );

try {
    $args = array(
        'orderId'=>'00119-23',
        'SecurityToken'=>'d989aaf6-ea3c-429e-996c-4722b1d2ce3e'
    );
    
    $result = $client->__soapCall('exportOrder', array($args));
    
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo "Error: {$e}";
    }
?>
```

And here is the xml in SOAPUI. I works when i indicate the SecurityToken and the orderId like this. I get the results.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mis="http://abcd.webservices.xyz.abcd.eu/">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <SecurityToken>d989aaf6-ea3c-429e-996c-4722b1d2ce3e</SecurityToken>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ord:exportOrder>
         <key>
            <orderId>00119-23</orderId>
         </key>
      </ord:exportOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to see other related topics, but it doesn't help (other issues are too specific)

Comment: Did you check [$client->getLastRequest()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) to see the request you formulated? I think SecurityToken should be in header and the order in your body might not be formatted correctly.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I tried  $client->getLastRequest() but it only answer: NULL. What do you mean by it should be in header? How can i do it in PHP in my code?